# IOS: Best way to show long articles with multiple images

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

I want to create an app for a news agency. The app has to display long articles with images/yotube videos like the news agencies website.

The article will come in json format from the api.

What is the best ways to do this so that the app looks and feels like the website.

NOTE: Cant use webViews so the options left are UITextField,UITextView for article inside a Table View or Scroll View?

What would be the best implementation?

[Example URL For Article](http://www.ozy.com/rising-stars/this-millennial-might-be-the-new-einstein/65094?utm_source=aah1&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=pp&utm_content=inf_256_92_2&tse_id=INF_f482bf90bac211e6b62fc95d7852453f)

Comment: Table view is the way to go due to cell reusablity.

Comment: I'm curious what you're up to. I to have been trying to figure out a good way to display lots of text for a news app I'm writing. Do you feel webViews would be the best implementation but you just aren't able to use them? Does anyone know what apple uses for the Apple News Format, do they just convert to html or are they native components?

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `UITableView` or a `UICollectionView`.

Answer (score 1):

I second dasdom......so that the view doesn't get boring (ie. the same style of cell all the way through) create 2-3 different reusable cells and call these to display different media.

Answer (score 0):

> I would suggest Use a Table view with show more and show less article content functionality with some kind of animation can be the best implementation for this.